# Once you have Ubuntu installed on a Nexus 7, how do you get back to stock Android?

Tags: nexus-7, linux, rom

I currently have a Nexus 7 with the default "out-of-the-box" Android Stock OS (as of this post JB 4.2.2).

From what I've read online, Ubuntu has made a mobile version of their OS. Usually, they specially demo their mobile OS with Google's Nexus devices.

I would like to try Ubuntu on my Nexus 7, but don't want to do it permanently. Though, I still want to have the experience as if Ubuntu runs the tablet, and not Android (Just to try something new and a change of pace).

I wanted to know that if I were to permanently to install Ubuntu on my Nexus 7 device, if and how would I get my device back to the stock Android OS that came with it "out-of-the-box"?

In other words, I know you are able to install Ubuntu on Android, but is it possible, once you have cleared Android off, and only Ubuntu exists, to go from Ubuntu back to Android?

Maybe I don't know enough about what happens when you install Ubuntu on an Android device, but if there is some detail that you feel is missing, please feel to fill in the blanks of my stupidity.

Comment: [Reinstall OS on Nexus 7](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40173/reinstall-os-on-nexus-7), [Is it possible to reinstall stock Android on the Nexus 7](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36732/is-it-possible-to-reinstall-stock-android-on-the-nexus-7) AFAIK a standard re-flash will work, but you could probably also do a backup in a custom recovery (ClockworkMod, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directions taken from *[OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/how-to-reinstall-android-on-nexus-devices)*. I’m assuming you backed up your data.

1. [Download the corresponding Android image from Google](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images).
2. Extract the downloaded ZIP.
3. Connect your Nexus 7 to the computer with the USB cable.
4. Open a Terminal window and type: `adb reboot-bootloader`, this will reboot the tablet into the Android bootloader.
5. In the terminal, use the `cd` command to enter the folder created after you extracted the previously downloaded ZIP, for example, `Desktop/<name of extracted folder>`
6. Once there, run the shell script: `sudo ./flash-all.sh` and wait for it to complete.